# Kendo grid add custom footer

Tags: kendo-ui, grid

I used kendo grid, I need to add custom footer with predefined text.

Please suggest me. Thanks in advance[image]

Note : 
1) Aggregate function column footer template is not needed

Answer (score 2):

You will need use jQuery and css to do that. I am afraid, that there is not possibility to modify footer. Maybe [footerTemplate](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.footerTemplate) can help you.

Anyway, if you have to, you can append anything you want - for example in dataBound event. Small [example](http://dojo.telerik.com/iYAro) here.